# Cypress - select an option without using text or value

Tags: testing, automation, cypress

This is what I am trying to select:

```
<select id="firstDate" name="firstDate" class="ab-abcd sdfg">
<option disabled="" value="">First day</option>
<option value="01.02.2019">01.02.2019</option>
<option value="01.02.2019">01.02.2019</option>
</select>
```

This dates will change every now and than, so is there a way to select an option with Cypress without using

```
cy.get('#firstDate').select('01.01.2019')
```

?

I also tried with

```
cy.get('#firstDate').first()
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5):

I think that the best way to change the value is via `.select()`. If you try to force click an option, it won't change the selected value.

What is the reason that makes this values change? If they are generated from a server request you can try to stub it [like this](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#With-Stubbing). If they are generated given the current date, you could try [using clocks](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clock.html#Syntax)

Edit After knowing what makes the selectors dynamic:

To fix a date for your tests and make them consistent you can do

```
// fix the date before rendering the select
const now = new Date(2019, 01, 15).getTime() //  2019-01-02 timestamp
cy.clock(now)

cy.visit('/index.html') // visit the page to test (or make actions that render the select)
cy.get('#firstDate').select('01.02.2019') // select one month beyond
cy.get('#firstDate').select('01.03.2019') // select two months beyond
```

Comment: Stubbing is the best idea. It is always better to use predictable content in a test.

Comment: Well this is used for registering, so this is kind of a start date which will always be  in the future -  first day of + one month in the future and  first day of + two months in the future.

Comment: I have updated my answer with specific code for your use case. I use `clock()` to fix the time and make the test consistent

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for your answers. In the meantime a found a solution that works for me:

```
    cy.get('#FirstDate')
   .find('option')
   .then($elm => $elm.get(1).setAttribute('selected', "selected"))
   .parent()
   .trigger('change')
```

But I will try out your suggestions too and let you know what happened.

Answer (score 1):

You were very close with your second attempt, but you are getting the `select` element, not the `option` elements.  Try this:

```
cy.get('select#firstDate').click() // Open the dropdown
cy.get('select#firstDate > option')
  .eq(1) // The second option, because the first is a heading
  .click()
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried but I get this error message:
"CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.click() failed because this element is not visible:

<option disabled="" value="">Fyrsti ...</option>

This element '<option>' is not visible because it has an effective width and height of: '0 x 0' pixels.

Fix this problem, or use {force: true} to disable error checking."

I tried with {force: true} but it just skips the dropdown.

Comment: Are you opening the dropdown first?  I'm guessing it is not open.  Add `cy.get("select#firstDate").click()` first.  I'll update my answer

Comment: But how can I click on a select element? That throws an error

Comment: Ah, the first element is not one of the options that you can click, it is the heading "First day".  You will have to select the *second* element, you can do that with `.eq(1)` instead of `.first()`.  After reading your comment on @AlexSerra's answer to provide more context, you can set the state to be consistent which will allow you to use `.select()`.  That is a much better way of handling this, now that you can know the value to select.